# Producer consumer in java multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I have my own implementation of producer and consumer in java multithreading. But consumer gets the product before producer puts the product. How to overcome this using wait and notify.

```
package prod;

public class InitProCon {

volatile static int size = 5;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Consumer con = new Consumer("Consumer Getting", size);
    Producer pro = new Producer("Producer putting", size);
    Thread producer = new Thread(pro);
    Thread consumer = new Thread(con);
    producer.start();
    consumer.start();
}
}


package prod;

public class Product {

static String product;

public void putProduct(String product) {
    Product.product = product;
}

public String getProduct() {
    return product;
}
}




package prod;

public class Consumer implements Runnable {

String cname;
int size;

Consumer(String name, int size) {
    this.cname = name;
    this.size = size;
    System.out.println(cname);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Product c = new Product();
            c.getProduct();
            System.out.println("Consumer got product" + i + ""
                    + c.getProduct());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
}



package prod;

public class Producer implements Runnable {

String pname;
int size;

Producer(String name, int size) {
    this.pname = name;
    this.size = size;
    System.out.println(pname);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Product p = new Product();
            p.putProduct("Consumer product");
            System.out.println("Producer put" + i);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Read their javadoc, read the Java concurrency tutorial, and try something. Or better, use a BlockingQueue, shared by the producer and the consumer, to store the products. This is much easier, and much less error-prone.

Comment: This implementation is nowhere near a Producer Consumer problem. Use a fixed size shared data structure like a queue or an array which can be accessed by producer and the consumer. The consumer cannot consume if there is no data in the queue, it will wait for the producer to produce. The producer after producing data will notify the waiting consumer. Try it out, you won't get it unless you try.

Comment: I would go this far and call a Producer/Consumer pattern deprecated.

Comment: You can find working example with out wait() and notify() at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683895/wait-and-notify-in-consumer-and-producer-threads/37686902#37686902

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have different product contents, you only have one:

```
package prod;
public class Product {
    static String product;
    public void putProduct(String product) {
        Product.product = product;
```

Notice the `static`: All products (`Product` objects) share the same content. So when your producer produces a new product

```
        Product p = new Product();
        p.putProduct("Consumer product");
```

you set the content for *all* products. So it may *seem* that the consumers get the same product but that is not quite correct. Every consumer gets a different object of type `Product` but all products share the same content. By creating the new product you change the content of existing products also. When outputting you can't notice the difference because you only use an artificial index and the shared content (would you use a object specific value like `hashCode´ you could see that those are different objects).