# Wait and notify in Consumer and Producer Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, producer-consumer, notify

Just started learning multi-threading. I have 5 producers and 2 consumers in multiple threads. Basically this program adds 100 items into the queue. The producer will stop adding when the queue size is 100. I would like the consumer to notify the producer when the consumer removes all the items from the queue so that the producer can start adding again. Currently the producer will wait but never gets notified by the consumer.

Producer:

```
public class Producer implements Runnable {

private BlockingQueue sharedQueue;
private final int queueSize;
private Object lock = new Object();

  public Producer(BlockingQueue sharedQueue, int queueSize){
    this.sharedQueue = sharedQueue;
    this.queueSize = queueSize;
  }

  public void run() {
    while(true) {
        if(sharedQueue.size()== queueSize){

                try {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                    sharedQueue.wait();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
         }

        try {
            sharedQueue.put("Producer: " + sharedQueue.size());
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.println("Producer:  Queue Size " + sharedQueue.size() + " Current Thread " + Thread.currentThread());

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

consumer:

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable{

private BlockingQueue sharedQueue;
private final int queueSize;
private final int queueEmpty=0;
private Object lock = new Object();

   public Consumer(BlockingQueue sharedQueue, int queueSize){
    this.sharedQueue = sharedQueue;
    this.queueSize = queueSize;
   }
//Notify awaiting thread if the sharedQueue is empty
   public void run() {
    while (true) {
        if(sharedQueue.size()==queueEmpty){
            synchronized (lock) {
            this.notifyAll();
            }
        }
            try {

                    sharedQueue.take();
                    Thread.sleep(800);
                    System.out.println("Consumer: Queue Size " + sharedQueue.size() + " Current Thread" + Thread.currentThread());

            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

  }
}
```

Main class

```
  public class App{ 

//A simple program to illustrate how producer and consumer pattern works with blocking queue using executor service
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    final BlockingQueue<String> sharedQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String> (100);
    final int queueSize =100;
    final int producerNum = 5;
    final int consumerNum = 2;

    final ExecutorService executorProducer = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(producerNum);
    final ExecutorService executorConsumer = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(consumerNum);

    for(int i=0;i<producerNum;i++){
        Producer producer = new Producer(sharedQueue,queueSize);
        executorProducer.execute(producer);
    }

    for(int j=0;j<consumerNum;j++){
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(sharedQueue,queueSize);
        executorConsumer.execute(consumer);
    }



   }
 }
```

Comment: What do you think `this.notifyAll();` does? Why do you think so?

Comment: this code should throw IllegalMonitorStateException if notifyAll gets called.

Comment: I think notifyAll will wake up all threads that are waiting on this object. The awakened threads will not be able to proceed until the current thread relinquishes the lock on this object. So my mistake here is that wait and notify need to be used on the same object?

Comment: @Nathan exactly...

Comment: There are multiple mistakes here. Reading the Oracle tutorial on guarded blocks should teach you something.

Comment: For guarded block examples, the wait and notifyAll methods are called out in the object which is updated by both producer and consumer. Also they toggle a boolean variable to trigger the while loop. I understand that example, but when I call sharedQueue.wait() or sharedQueue.notifyAll(), I will get the illegalMonitorStateException

Comment: @Nathan I have made a couple of edits to the code. It still shows the same error message. Seems that putting synchronized block around wait and notifyall do not solve the problem...

Comment: i told you there are multiple problems. read the oracle tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: you do not need to wait/notify when you are using blocking queue, as the queue will be blocked when it reaches the limit for the producer and for consumer when there is no more task left in the queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From oracle documentation [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html):

> BlockingQueue implementations are thread-safe. All queuing methods achieve their effects atomically using internal locks or other forms of concurrency control

Since you are already using `BlockingQueues`, you can get rid of `wait()` and `notify()` APIs.

Example code for multiple producer and consumers using `BlockingQueue`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class ProducerConsumerDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]){

     BlockingQueue<Integer> sharedQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>();

      Thread prodThread1 = new Thread(new Producer(sharedQueue,1));
      Thread prodThread2 = new Thread(new Producer(sharedQueue,2));
      Thread consThread1 = new Thread(new Consumer(sharedQueue,1));
      Thread consThread2 = new Thread(new Consumer(sharedQueue,2));

      prodThread1.start();
      prodThread2.start();
      consThread1.start();
      consThread2.start(); 
   }

}

class Producer implements Runnable {

    private final BlockingQueue<Integer> sharedQueue;
    private int threadNo;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue<Integer> sharedQueue,int threadNo) {
        this.threadNo = threadNo;
        this.sharedQueue = sharedQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=1; i<= 5; i++){
            try {
                int number = i+(10*threadNo);
                System.out.println("Produced:" + number + ":by thread:"+ threadNo);
                sharedQueue.put(number);
            } catch (Exception err) {
                err.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

class Consumer implements Runnable{

    private final BlockingQueue<Integer> sharedQueue;
    private int threadNo;
    public Consumer (BlockingQueue<Integer> sharedQueue,int threadNo) {
        this.sharedQueue = sharedQueue;
        this.threadNo = threadNo;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            try {
                int num = sharedQueue.take();
                System.out.println("Consumed: "+ num + ":by thread:"+threadNo);
            } catch (Exception err) {
               err.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

How does it work?

1. Producer Thread 1 puts Integers ranging from 11 - 15into `BlockingQueue`
2. Producer Thread 2 puts Integers ranging from 21 - 25 into `BlockingQueue`
3. Any of Consumer Threads - Thread 1 or Thread 2 reads values from `BlockingQueue` (Integer in this example)

Sample output:

```
Produced:21:by thread:2
Produced:11:by thread:1
Produced:12:by thread:1
Produced:13:by thread:1
Produced:14:by thread:1
Produced:22:by thread:2
Produced:23:by thread:2
Produced:24:by thread:2
Produced:25:by thread:2
Consumed: 21:by thread:1
Consumed: 12:by thread:1
Consumed: 13:by thread:1
Consumed: 14:by thread:1
Consumed: 22:by thread:1
Consumed: 23:by thread:1
Consumed: 24:by thread:1
Consumed: 25:by thread:1
Produced:15:by thread:1
Consumed: 11:by thread:2
Consumed: 15:by thread:1
```