# Accessing objects between theads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, websocket

I have a class that extends websocket. In this class it calls something that will return messages once a second. In my onMessage function I do various processing where i put data into an array of Short on every message (once a second currently). My question is i want to spawn a new thread that runs a class to read this array and write it to a file once a second. How do i spawn a new thread with get/set functionality to variables in the original class? Reason behind this is that the reader thread needs to clear some elements in the array once it has written to a file. Note that i want to have the read and write threads independant so the rates can be changed without affecting each other.

Comment: Have a look at working code in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683895/wait-and-notify-in-consumer-and-producer-threads/37686902#37686902

Answer (score 2):

You could use a traditional, producer-consumer model: write to a [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) from your onMessage function, and read it from a separate thread that writes its content to a file.